# WAMP server not able to be put online

Tags: apache, wamp, wampserver, apache2.2

I've recently install WAMP 2.2 on my Windows PC. For whatever reason, my WAMP server isn't working. I try to open php files on my localhost but I get the famous 404 error message. The icon is orange and says that it is online, but that 404 error is showing me otherwise.Any ideas as to why it isn't working for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Just go to test port 80. If its being used by another process, you can defined your own port at httpd.conf
Search and find the following string on file httpd.conf1

```
   Listen 80
```

and change to

```
   Listen {to desired port like 8888}
```

Answer (score 2):

Cant vote nor comment (first time here) but I had this same issue. Under ***Apache/Service*** I tried to restart the server but it wasn't even started, then I tried installing it but it said another program was using port 80.

**Solution**: Closed Skype, ***Apache/Service/Install Service*** and then restarted all services. Was able to put wamp server online and finally localhost was up and running.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with WAMP once and my problem was that skype was running and using a port that WAMP wanted to use. Don't know if this is your problem, but if skype is running try shutting it down & rebooting WAMP

Comment: I read about that as well, however I don't have Skype installed on this computer :/

Comment: Stupid question maybe, but have you tried 127.0.0.1:portnumber as url?

Answer (score 0):

Other ways to fix this problem:

1. Install Apache Service (Apache > Install Service) or
2. Remove and re-install Apache Service (Apache > Remove Service)

Answer (score 0):

Wampmanager reports errors to Windows Event Viewer. When I realized this I was able to find that it didn't like my httpd.conf  e.g.

```
The Apache service named  reported the following error:
httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 77 of C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/conf/httpd.conf
Cannot   load modules/mod_access_compat.so into server: 
The specified module could not be found.
```

My real crime however was to lazily reuse a httpd.conf from an older version of WAMP instead of reconfiguring the default version supplied.